# Нужна помощь в определении смысла предложения. Помогите разобраться!

Tags: пунктуация

*— Сколько тебе лет?

— Мне в 10 раз больше, чем было тебе,  когда мне было как тебе сейчас.*

Помогите перевести на русский!!!

Comment: Вообще-то вполне по-русски. Какое слово непонятно? Если вам надо эту задачку решить, то она элементарна, но не на ресурсе же русского языка этим заниматься.

Comment: Конечно, составьте просто два уравнения с тремя неизвестными и рассмотрите целые значения.

Answer (score 0):

> Удаву 110. Сколько тебе лет, спросил он у черепахи. Черепаха ответила:
>   мне в 10 раз больше, чем было тебе, когда мне было как тебе сейчас. 
>   Сколько лет черепахе?

Здесь и решение и объяснение.
http://www.smekalka.pp.ru/math/answer_math_calc_64.html

Если разберетесь, глядишь, и по русскому языку вопросов не будет.

//============
Попросили дать решение. )))

Пусть ***X*** - возраст черепахи.
Черепахе было ***110*** лет ***(X-110)*** лет назад.
Удаву тогда было ***110-(X-110)***.
По условию ***(110-(X-110))*10=X***
Отсюда ***11X=2200*** и ***X=200***.
Черепахе ***200*** лет.

Проверяем.
90 лет назад ей было 110 - как сейчас удаву. Удаву тогда было 20 лет - в десять раз меньше, чем черепахе сейчас. Именно это и требовалось в условии.

Comment: Без ответа ответ не ответ; одной ссылки недостаточно. Нужны цитаты, иначе — комментарий...

Comment: @Aer посмотрите внимательно. Ответ дан. **Удаву 110 лет**. Разбирать математику считаю излишним. Других вопросов тут и не было.

Comment: Но это же ответ без пояснений...

Comment: А здесь и не надо пояснений. Впрочем, как скажете. Напишу решение. Но под вашу ответственность.

Comment: Я вас понимаю ) но тогда нужно было бы закрыть непрофильный вопрос, а вы решили дать ответ... тогда уж по всем рекомендациям оформлять стоит, стало быть...

Comment: Так закрывайте.. Я не против. Но вообще-то автор спрашивал не про решение. Он, типа,  смысл не мог понять - а это уже претензия на русский язык. Как ему можно помочь? Я дал ссылку на решение, если разберётся, то и смысл вопроса станет ясным. Вот и все.

Answer (score 0):

По-хорошему Вам следовало бы задать этот вопрос [на сайте по математике](https://math.stackexchange.com/), но для этого Вам придется сначала выучить английский язык, т.к. там все на английском.
Поэтому попробую объяснить Вам здесь по-русски, как составить простейшее уравнение для решения этой задачи. Очень надеюсь, что коллеги простят меня за это небольшое отклонение от основной тематики сайта.

Итак, предположим, что задающему вопрос сейчас **а** лет.
Пусть тогда нынешний возраст того, кому задают вопрос, равен **x**.
Соответственно разница в возрасте будет **x - a**.

Когда тому, кому задают вопрос, было столько же, сколько сейчас задающему, т.е. **а** лет, задающему было **а - (x - a)**, т.е. **2a - x** лет. А так как мы знаем, что это в **10** раз меньше, чем **x**, получаем простейшее уравнение с параметром:
**x = 10 * (2a - x)**

Раскрываем скобки и решаем уравнение:
**x = 20a - 10x**
**11х = 20а**
**х = 20а / 11**

***Говоря простым русским языком:*** отвечающий предлагает задающему вопрос умножить возраст задающего на **20** и затем разделить на **11**, чтобы узнать интересующий его возраст.
Просто ответ этот дан, скажем так, в несколько иносказательной форме, *как это и положено в большой литературе*.

Comment: Вы простите, серьезно? Математика тут элементарная, в одно действие. А если человек не понимает условие задачи, то у него будет только больше вопросов от таких ваших пояснений.

Comment: *т.к. там все на английском.* Есть и на русском аналог. http://math.hashcode.ru/  Впрочем, там задачи посерьезнее рассматривают.